# Task Module is not closing on clicking on the new message Notification popup in the Teams client App

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have created a personal tab and opening a task module from that. If we get any new chat notification (for new message popup in bottom right side) and the task module is already opened, that particular chat detail is opening on the background but the opened task module popup is not closing. Close button on the task module is also not working we need to restart the Teams client App.
The below is the code for start task module in the node.js
let url = window.location.origin + "/GetData?" + id ;let taskInfo = {url: url,title: "Get Info",height: 300,width: 600,fallbackUrl: url}
microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask(taskInfo, (err, result) => {console.log(`Submit handler - err: ${err}`);microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask();});

Comment: We are unable to repro the issue.We are using following sample to repro the scenario-
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-adaptive-cards/nodejs
also attached the video-https://youtu.be/rV5MOfhnr9E

Comment: In the Video you are not getting the bottom right message popup when some other person pinged may be settings change

Comment: please check video-https://youtu.be/QrT4q4LtZ74

Comment: once you clicked on the chat then you will navigate to the chat ,task module will also be there on that chat,then you are not able to close that task module that is the issue we are facing (i.e.) if we open the task module if any one pinged that  time without closing the popup if we navigate to the chat then popup of the task module will be there after that we are not able to close that popup that is the issue we are facing

Comment: In which Ring(Teams) you are tested the task module ?

Comment: i have tested in the client app(Desktop version) not in the web in web its working fine the issue is only with the client app (desktop )

Comment: Its working fine if we add  microsoftTeams.registerBeforeUnloadHandler((handler) => {


            handler = true;
            return false;
        }); in the app.js

Comment: We recently checked as you mentioned above. It's working fine from our end-
https://youtu.be/z-IvIhutguM
 Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.21302 (64-bit)-E.